# Use checkbox in switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, checkbox, switch-statement

I'm creating a site where I want different divs to appear depending on the combination of checkboxes checked. I need to know how to refer to the class of the checkboxs in a switch statement. Here's what I have so far. Any suggestions on how I can make it work?

I'm trying to use "class" to refer to the class of the checkboxes. For example, if I click on checkbox3, and checkbox1 is already clicked, I want div2 to appear. If checkbox1 was not clicked, I want div4 to appear.

```
$ (".checkbox3").click(function(){    
 switch ($('input:checkbox:checked').attr('class')) {
  case ".checkbox1" && ".checkbox2":
    $(".div1").fadeIn("slow");
    break;
  case ".checkbox1":
    $(".div2").fadeIn("slow");
    break;
  case ".checkbox2":
    $(".div3").fadeIn("slow");
    break;
  default:
    $(".div4").fadeIn("slow");
    break;
    }
    });
```

Here's the HTML code it's refering to.

```
<form>
 <input type="checkbox" id="redcheck" class="checkbox1">
 <input type="checkbox" id="greencheck" class="checkbox2">
 <input type="checkbox" id="bluecheck" class="checkbox3">
</form> 
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
<div class="div4"></div>
```

Any help would be really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Put your html code also

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `$("class")` part?

Comment: And in general, can you clarify your question? I've read it three times now, and I'm afraid I just have no idea what you actually want to do.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, the question is now updated. I'm trying to make different image appear depending on the combination of checkboxes checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to checked checkboxes in jquery as following:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked')
```

What you can do is something like this:

```
 $ (".checkbox3").change(function(){    
    var val='';

    if($(this).is(':checked')) {

        $.each($('input:checkbox:checked:not(.checkbox3:checkbox)'), function(index) {
            val += '.' + $(this).attr('class');        
        });

        switch (val) {
            case '.checkbox1.checkbox2':
                $(".div1").fadeIn(400);
                console.log('case 1');
                break;
            case '.checkbox1':
                $(".div2").fadeIn(400);
                console.log('case 2');
                break;
            case '.checkbox2':
                $(".div3").fadeIn(400);
                console.log('case 3');
                break;
            default:
                $(".div4").fadeIn(400);
                console.log('case 4');
                break;
        }
    } else {
        $('div[class*="div"]').hide(); 
    }
 });
```

Here is [link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7nae6xL/28/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would you happen to know how I can refer to the class of the checkboxes?

Comment: @YvonneQiao in fiddle fadeIn animation not working in my browser. Does it working in your case?

Comment: Yes, the fiddle fadeIn animation is working as soon as I set display to none. Thank you. I am trying to implement this into my more complicated string of code, and I'm having some issues to work out. But this is definitely helpful!

Comment: @YvonneQiao I updated code little bit. And you can find try it in fiddle.